# How to pass select statement values inside the full index search in mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I would like to pass `select body from articles` result-set instead of `database` as a keyword inside the `AGAINST` parameter list. How can I do that?. I want to find the related articles based on the matching keywords from the table.

```sql
SELECT * FROM articles
     WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

I want do to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM articles
     WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ("select title,body from articles" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Edit from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798205/how-to-pass-select-statement-values-inside-the-full-index-search-in-mysql#comment11008581_8810459):
 I would like to get the related article based on the density of the matching keywords in the article channel. I have created the `FULLTEXT` index and my table is in ISAM format. Currently the article channel contains subtitle and body custom fields. Since everything has to be dynamic so I cannot pass the keywords inside the `AGAINST('Lorem Manager')` because we don't know what will be the keywords when we visit the next news article, so I embed select statement to pull the title and body. I am getting result but somehow my stop keywords are not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

What are you hoping to achieve, exactly?

To better understand — *and perhaps illustrate* — what you're asking for, **let's discuss things in ExpressionEngine parlance**, after all that's what you tagged your question with.

Using the Agile Records ExpressionEngine site theme, let's use two fields from the *About* channel — Body and Staff Member's Title:

> **Body**
>   Custom Field: `{about_body}`
>   MySQL Column: `field_id_4`
>
> **Staff Member's Title**
>   Custom Field: `{about_staff_title}`
>   MySQL Column: `field_id_6`

First, if you haven't already, you need to [create a single FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) that contains all of the columns you're searching on.

Using the two columns from above, execute the following SQL statement from phpMyAdmin or your favorite MySQL GUI Client:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX related_articles
    ON exp_channel_data (field_id_4, field_id_6);
```

You can verify the newly created INDEX with the following query:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM exp_channel_data;
```

To perform a natural language search for a string (keywords) against a text collection (one or more database columns), consider the following ... where *Lorem* and *Manager* are your keywords:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data
    WHERE MATCH (field_id_4, field_id_6)
    AGAINST ('Lorem Manager' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Which would return a result set like the following (simplified for readability):

```
+----------+-------------+------------------------+
| entry_id | field_id_4  | field_id_6             |
+----------+-------------+------------------------+
|        3 | Lorem ipsum |                        |
|        8 |             | Product Manager        |
|        4 |             | Co-Owner/Label Manager |
+----------+-------------+------------------------+
```

When using natural-language full-text searches, it is a requirement that the columns named in the MATCH() function be the same columns included in some FULLTEXT index in your table.

For instance, in the preceding example note that the columns named in the MATCH() function (**field_id_4** and **field_id_6**) are the same as those named in the definition of the article table's FULLTEXT index.

If you wanted to search the columns *separately*, you would need to create separate FULLTEXT indexes for each column.

---

Some words are ignored in full-text searches:

- Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.
- Words in the stopword list are ignored. A stopword is a word such as “the” or “some” that is so common that it is considered to have zero semantic value. There is a built-in stopword list, but it can be overwritten by a user-defined list.

The default stop word list can be viewed in [11.9.4. Full-Text Stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) of the MySQL Documentation.

Comment: Thanks rjb for the detail explanation. I would like to get the related article based on the density of the matching keywords in the article channel.I have created the FULLTEXT index and my table is in ISAM format.Currently the article channel contains subtitle and body custom fields.Since everything has to be dynamic so I cannot pass the keywords inside the AGAINST('Lorem Manager') because we don't know what will be the keywords when we visit the next news article, so I embed select statement to pull the title and body.I am getting result but somehow my stop keywords are not recognized.